# is there a Heroku type hosting solution for python/web2py?

Tags: python, heroku, web-hosting, web2py

I am interested to know if there are any python/web2py hosting platforms similar to Heroku for Ruby on Ralils? Something that is easily configurable and scalable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several cloud providers, the one I've personally used is http://dotcloud.com/ and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [DotCloud](http://dotcloud.com), there's [ep.io](http://www.ep.io/), [AppHosted](https://apphosted.com/), [Pydra](http://www.pydra.com/), and [Stable.io](http://stable.io/).

Comment: Pydra's site has crashed.  Apphosted has an SSL error, but otherwise seems to be real.  Stable.io and ep.io are both at the stage of "give us your email and we'll let you know when we have something."

Comment: A lot can happen in a year. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is also [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/?affiliate_id=000003e9) which is referenced in the Web2Py docs

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: We also host http://www.web2py.com and http://www.web2pyslices.com

Answer (score 2):

As Heroku now supports Python, has anyone managed to deploy a web2py app to Heroku?

And you can add [Fluxflex](http://www.fluxflex.com) to the list ;)

Comment: Fluxflex's support tells me they shut down last month.

Comment: Yes, they did. Too bad because web2py was working as a charm on Fluxflex.